# How to compare cucumber fields with pojo elements from json

Tags: java, json, cucumber, rest-assured, pojo

I have a json:

```
{
    "id": "12",
    "title": "Records",
    "contents": [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "type": "medium"
        },
        {
            "id": "222",
            "type": "low"
        }
    ],
    "description": "lalala",
    "category": {
        "id": "000111",
        "name": "Basic Name"
    }
}
```

And I need to validate if there are certain values there. I use cucumber
So in Cucumber I declare:

```
 And Below fields matches
          | category.name| Basic Name |
          | category.id   | 000111 |
```

How to compare them? I have json deserialized to pojo classes.

Now, I tried something like this:

```
ValidatableResponse json = response.then().statusCode(200);
for(Map.Entry<String, String> field: table.entrySet()) {
    json.body(field.getKey(), containsInAnyOrder(field.getValue()));
}
```

...but it throws error:

```
> JSON path category.name doesn't match. Expected: iterable with items
> ["Basic Name"] in any order   Actual: Basic Name
```

Also, tried:

```
public void mapsMatch(Map<String, String> table) {
Map<String, String> expectedFieldsValues = new HashMap<>(table);

Map<String, String>  map1 = response.jsonPath().get();
Assert.assertTrue(map1.entrySet().containsAll((expectedFieldsValues.entrySet())));
}
```

but also throws AssertionError.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, help?

Comment: try this
 And Below fields matches
          | category.name| "Basic Name" |
          | category.id   | "000111" |

Comment: @yahitesh no, it's not that >> Expected: iterable with items ["\"Basic Name\""] in any order
  Actual: Basic Name